# Testnet status for web portal

Tags: eosio-code, testnet

Is any else facing testnet 502 gateway error when trying to access the front end web portal for the testnet.

Answer (score 0):

is this the url you are using?
https://testnet.eos.io/

it loads fine for me, no 502
from what geo are you trying to load it? (can you disclose this info?)

LATER EDIT:
it should work now for you, please confirm.

Comment: yes I am using mentioned URL, I am accessing it from Pakistan

Comment: can you please tell if https://testnet.eos.io/ now for you?